# Why does my Windows 10 computer sound like a helicopter while just reading with Chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a ASUS ROG STRIX G15 with RTX 3060, and Ryzen 7, Win10. I'm not doing anything that could cause a virus to come (it might be the reason though). I'm a Mac user in general. You only hear a Mac working when it's really working, not reading in a single browser tab (not even scrolling).

Yes, I get it, updates, processes behind the scenes, but this often? The computer has intervals of few minutes when it goes silent, then mad, repeating.

Is this normal?

Comment: Instead of just guestimating what happens from the fan noise, investigate! Task Manager can tell you a lot about how busy the PC is and possibly also which program is responsible. With hardware monitoring software you can check whether the temperatures are okay. // Also keep in mind that it’s not a MacBook. Windows notebooks often have trash fan speed control.

Comment: You might also want to try switching to the Balanced power profile by clicking the battery icon, I suspect it is set to High Performance which has little benefit and will cause the fans to work harder

Comment: @DanielB Task Manager doesn't say anything special. When I open it though for a blink of an eye it shows CPU usage 60-70%, then jump down to 5%. That was suspicious previously too, and tried some commands to see more raw data, but couldn't go forward with the info, so just left it. But it has became annoying enough, so have to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As you bought a gaming oriented laptop, by default performance is the only concern and not silent operation. **It's probably related to your fan configuration in BIOS/UEFI.** On an ASUS of my own the fans were configured to adjust based on the reported CPU temperature immediately. When launching an app / website the laptop CPU works hard for a fraction of a second, resulting in a short temperature peak. This caused the fans to ramp up like all hell broke loose nevertheless.

**You may change the fan curve / fan step up duration in UEFI.** Pressing F2 on startup should get you into UEFI, there you may go into the "Advanced Mode" (F7), go to "Monitor" in the top bar and increase the values for fan step up. You may also open QFan Control (F6) and choose the predefined silent fan curve or adjust the fan curve manually.